# How to solve the Error: the image '***/xxxxx:latest' in container group 'xxx' is not accessible. please check the image and registry credential

Tags: docker, github-actions

Several hours of research to find an answer.
Used github-actions.yml for actions.
When building got en error:

```
Error: the image '***/xxxxx:latest' in container group 'xxx' is not accessible. please check the image and registry credential.
```

On each web people suggested way to fancy ways of solving.
That's what I came to: => see below

Answer (score 2):

So the way out was quite easy.

- Firstly I checked my credentials. Just in case created a new service principle.  Saved credentials as Github secret key.
  Make sure there is no space when you add credential to github.
  Ex.
- {"asdasd"
- "aksdjkas"
- "lksjadas"}

  Github repo - secrets - add new secret...

2. Check if image: hub.docker_username/repo:latest was correct
3. Lastly checked that my hub.docker_repo is actually public

The last thing resolved the problem.

Comment: But be aware making the repo public does just that. Makes the image publicly available. Sometimes, often in corporate setups, that is not allowed or desired.

Comment: In my case I got this error when I try to create azure container instance selecting Source as Container registry repository. I did not get this error when I created container instance from azure container registry itself.
To fix this error, try to create container instance from container registry.